# Read file and build facts on swi-prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I need to read from a file where there are descriptions of facts, for example:

```
id: GO:0000008
name: thioredoxin
```

and I need build a fact with it, like as :`"gene(0000008,thioredoxin)."`

---added---
Hi, I have been searching info and I found the DCG clauses, apparently DCG solve the problem but I do not found a detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

here a sample, using SWI-Prolog helper library

```
:- [library(dcg/basics)].

read_fact(Fact) -->
    "id:", blanks, "GO:", string(DIGITS), "\n", "name:", blanks, string(NAME),
    {atom_codes(A_DIGITS, DIGITS),
     atom_codes(A_NAME, NAME),
     Fact =.. [gene, A_DIGITS, A_NAME]
    }.
```

yields

```
?- phrase(read_fact(F), "id: GO:0000008\nname: thioredoxin").
F = gene('0000008', thioredoxin) .
```

DCG are handy to test inlining strings, as you can see, but to work on files there is [phrase_from_file](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=phrase_from_file/2), from library(pure_input). Also, browse [library(dcg/basics)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/dcg/basics.pl) to learn about many useful 'scanners', like blanks//0 or string//1.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `Fact =.. [gene, A_DIGITS, A_NAME]` instead of changing the head to `read_fact(gene(A_DIGITS, A_NAME))`?

Comment: I was showing the possibility to assemble the fact maybe reading the functor from file - it's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very small script in perl/python/php or similar, to change the format into the one you like

For example in perl

my($id) = '';

while( <> ){

if( $id ne ''){

```
m/name:\s(\w+)$/;

print "gene( id, $1 ).\n";

$id = '';
```

}

else{

```
if( m/id:.*(\d+)/){ $id = $1; }
```

}

}